# Check all values in a list based on index

Tags: python, function, loops, if-statement

I have the following function... 
Is there a way i could somehow add a loop so that each value in the list gets checked. The code shows checking each index with an elif one at a time. I am just wondering if it possible to do it in a single elif block? I have about 500 values in my list so cant really make an elif for each index
What i tried and didnt work:

`for loop in range(0,5)` and then just putting `elif (str(df.iloc[i]['Name']) in x):`

`range(0,5)` in the index argument itself `elif (str(df.iloc[range(0,5)]['Name']) in x):`

```
def colourcode(x):
    if ( str('default') in x): 
        return '#fff034'
    elif (str(df.iloc[0]['Name']) in x):
        return '#ff0000'
    elif (str(df.iloc[1]['Name']) in x):
        return '#ff0000'
    elif (str(df.iloc[2]['Name']) in x):
        return '#ff0000'
    else:
        return '#000000'
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can, the catch here is you need to have a dictionary with mappings, code goes as follows

```
code_mappings = {0: '#ff0000', 1: '#ff0000', 2: '#ff0000'}
def color_code(x):
 if(str('default') in x):
  return '#fff034'
 for i in range(2):
  if str(df.iloc[i]['Name'] in x)
     return code_mappings[i]
 return '#000000'
```

Comment: @user3925163 yes the above code returns a single color

Comment: 0,1,2 were just an example i have a very big list, cant make a dictionary for every index
is there another way?

Answer (score 0):

The built-in function [any](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#any) is a good fit for this.

If you want to test with every element in iloc :

```
def color_code(x):
    if(str('default') in x):
        return '#fff034'
    elif any(str(iloc['Name']) in x for iloc in df.iloc):
        return "#ff0000"
    return '#000000'
```

Within a slice of ilements in iloc :

```
any(str(iloc['Name']) in x for iloc in df.iloc[:3])
```

If iloc is not iterable :

```
any(str(df.iloc[i]['Name']) in x for i in range(3))
```

Comment: i am getting the following error
NotImplementedError: ix is not iterable

Comment: I editted to handle the case where df.iloc is not iterable